# E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout D/OpenGLRenderer: eglDestroySurface = 0x730c9a02d0

Tags: java, android

I am facing these problem about Recyclerview No adapter attached.
This is my Locat:

```
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
D/OpenGLRenderer: eglDestroySurface = 0x730c9a02d0
D/ViewRootImpl@8aa7e83[AddPostActivity]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0] 
[1080,1920] new=[0,0][1080,1920] result=0x5 surface={valid=false 0} 
changed=true
W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for YtyKXov13lReyirA8U4iritiUs6220-July- 
201910: 39 found on class gurungdinesh.com.sisapen.ModelPost
W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for pdMZtSaxkzd5Uul592qwXKawnaI220-July- 
201910: 40 found on class gurungdinesh.com.sisapen.ModelPost
D/FA: Connected to remote service
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=498KB, data=332KB
I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=498KB, data=332KB
I/zygote64: Increasing code cache capacity to 2MB
D/ViewRootImpl@f8f3e40[MainActivity2]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: frame=Rect(0, 
0 - 1080, 1920) ci=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) or=1
MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
```

This is my Adapter:

```
public class AdapterPost extends  
RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterPost.MyHolder> {

Context context;
List<ModelPost> postList;

public AdapterPost(Context context, List<ModelPost>postList) {
this.context = context;
this.postList = postList;

}


@NonNull
@Override
public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int 
viewType) {

//inflate layout
    View view = 
LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_users_posts, 
viewGroup, false);

    return new MyHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyHolder myHolder, int i) {
//get data
    String fullname = postList.get(i).getFullname();
    String date = postList.get(i).getDate();
    String time = postList.get(i).getTime();
    String Title = postList.get(i).getTitle();
    String Writing = postList.get(i).getWriting();

    //set data
    myHolder.uNameTv.setText(fullname);
    myHolder.pTimeTv.setText(time);
    myHolder.pDate.setText(date);
    myHolder.pTitileTv.setText(Title);
    myHolder.pWritingTv.setText(Writing);


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return postList.size();
}

//view holder class
class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    //views from users post
    ImageButton moreBtn;
    CircularImageView uPictureIv;
    TextView uNameTv, pTimeTv, pTitileTv, pWritingTv, pLikesTv, pDate;
    Button likebtn, commentBtn, shareBtn;

    private MyHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        //init views
        uPictureIv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.uPictureTv);
        uNameTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.uNameTv);
        pTimeTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pTimeTv);
        moreBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.moreBtn);
        pDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pDateTv);
        pTitileTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pTitleTv);
        pWritingTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pWriting);
        pLikesTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pLikesTv);
        likebtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.likeBtn);
        commentBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.commentBtn);
        shareBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.shareBtn);

    }
```

This is my HomeFragment:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
private FirebaseAuth mFirebase;
private DatabaseReference databaseReference;


private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private List<ModelPost> postList;
private AdapterPost adapterPost;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable 
ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_activity, container, 
false);


    //init
    mFirebase = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    databaseReference = 
 FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("posts");

    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.all_user_post_list);

    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new 
LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    postList = new ArrayList<>();

    loadPosts();

    return view;
}

private void loadPosts() {
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


            postList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                ModelPost modelPost = ds.getValue(ModelPost.class);

                postList.add(modelPost);

                //adapter
                adapterPost = new AdapterPost(getActivity(), postList);
                //set adapter to RecyclerView
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterPost);


            }

        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            //in case of error
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + 
databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

I have tried so many things but nothing happen.

Answer (score 0):

Since Firebase Tasks are Async the `setAdapter` method is called after your `return view;` in `onCreateView` method. That's why it gives the error `No adapter attached`. What you can do is call `setAdapter` in the `onCreateView` method and after you have populated the list, call [notifyDataSetChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifydatasetchanged). See the code below

```java
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private FirebaseAuth mFirebase;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private List<ModelPost> postList;
    private AdapterPost adapterPost;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable
            ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_activity, container,
                false);

        //init
        mFirebase = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        databaseReference =
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("posts");

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.all_user_post_list);

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new
                LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        postList = new ArrayList<>();
        // ----------- set the adapter here --------------------
        adapterPost = new AdapterPost(getActivity(), postList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterPost);

        loadPosts();

        return view;
    }

    private void loadPosts() {
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                postList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    ModelPost modelPost = ds.getValue(ModelPost.class);
                    postList.add(modelPost);
                }
                // ----------- call notifyDataSetChanged --------------------
                adapterPost.notifyDataSetChanged()

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                //in case of error
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" +
                        databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get this message because RecyclerView has no adapter set when the layout is drawn.

What you can do is that you can assign an empty adapter at start, i.e. in `onCreateView()`, then add the data to your adapter when you have it. This way you will not see this log. However, the first place you set the adapter is in a asynchronous code block. Everything is already drawn and the recyclerview hasn't provided an adapter yet, so it prints this log.